# Why this ODE doesn't have a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following problem:

$$u'' + u  = \sin t  ,\,\,  0 < t < \pi$$
$$u(0) = u(\pi)=0 $$

My book says that this problem doesn't have a solution (classic solution). I don't see how to obtain this.

Can someone give me a hint about how to prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you agree that the general solution to the ODE is $\left(c_1-\frac{t}{2}\right)\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)$? Then you have **two** conditions on values of $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general solution for the associated homogeneous equation is $u_h(t) = c \sin t + d \cos t$, with $c, d$ constants. Using undetermined coefficients, we can guess a particular solution of the form

$$u_p(t) = A t \sin t + B t \cos t$$

(the factor of $t$ is used since $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ already satisfy the homogeneous equation). Differentiating twice, and substituting into the equation, we'd find that $A = 0$ and $B = -1/2$. Combining this and writing down the general solution $u = u_h + u_p$, use the boundary data to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

If a solution of the ODE does exist, we will find
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin(t)^2 dt 
= \int_0^\pi \sin(t) \left[u''(t) + u(t)\right]  dt
= \int_0^\pi \left[\sin(t) \frac{d^2 u(t)}{dt^2} - u(t)\frac{d^2 \sin(t)}{dt^2}\right] dt\\
= \int_0^\pi \frac{d}{dt}\left[\sin(t)\frac{du(t)}{dt} -  u(t)\frac{d\sin(t)}{dt}\right] dt
= \left[\sin(t) u(t)' - u(t)\cos(t)\right]_0^\pi
= 0
$$
which is clearly wrong.